# How to save pygame Surface as an image to memory (and not to disk)

Tags: python, networking, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am developing a time-critical app on a Raspberry PI, and I need to send an image over the wire.
When my image is captured, I am doing like this:

```
# pygame.camera.Camera captures images as a Surface
pygame.image.save(mySurface,'temp.jpeg')
_img = open('temp.jpeg','rb')
_out = _img.read()
_img.close()
_socket.sendall(_out)
```

This is not very efficient. I would like to be able to save the surface as an image in memory and send the bytes directly without having to save it first to disk.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: The other side of the wire is a .NET app expecting bytes

Comment: Can you use `pygame.image.tostring`? Seems like what you want, but I can't find good documentation on the binary it produces.

Comment: Looks like PIL can load this format, try passing pygame.image.tostring to PIL, convert as needed and then send. I'll test when I can and write a proper answer

Comment: @kalhartt hey when you're writing your answer, I don't think youll need PIL. You can just take the string from `tostring` and use `pygame.image.fromstring()` on it. You will have to specify the size of the image and the format you are using. One common format is 'RGBA'.

Comment: @Shashank Gupta, that will work but I don't see any compressed formats that `tostring` and `fromstring` support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is:

```
surf = pygame.Surface((100,200)) # I'm going to use 100x200 in examples
data = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA')
```

and just send the data. But we want to compress it before we send it. So I tried this

```
from StringIO import StringIO
data = StringIO()
pygame.image.save(surf, x)
print x.getvalue()
```

Seems like the data was written, but I have no idea how to tell pygame what format to use when saving to a StringIO. So we use the roundabout way.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
data = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA')
img = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (100,200), data)
zdata = StringIO()
img.save(zdata, 'JPEG')
print zdata.getvalue()
```

Comment: thx, I think I forgot to mention that the other side of the pipe is a .NET app expecting bytes. The `tostring` works very well of course if the recipient is in Python.

Comment: @jhfelectric Both of these are strings of the raw bytes, equivalent to what you get from `open(name, "rb")`

Answer (score 1):

the fromstring method has been deprecated in PIL and replaced with from bytes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The question was asked 7 years ago, so some functionality could be deprecated. Please, edit your solution with the more "updated" solution