# Python: "Draw" with the mouse into a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, canvas, mouseevent

For the purpose of demonstrating a handwritten digit recognition system, I want to be able to draw digits with the mouse in a Python 3 application. The drawings must end up as gray scale raster images in a 28-by-28 Numpy array.

Since the digits must resemble the digits from the [MNIST dataset](https://www.google.se/search?q=mnist&tbm=isch) and therefore can't be aliased, it's probably best if I can draw with thick strokes on a large canvas, read the image into a Numpy array and then downsample it.

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit:** Initially, I considered using a Tkinter canvas to do the drawing, but there seems to be [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511973/1070480) to get a rasterized version of a Tkinter canvas drawing.

Comment: You can take a look at pygame to make tha drawing tool. and [saving to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193187/how-to-save-pygame-surface-as-an-image-to-memory-and-not-to-disk) so you can work with it.

Comment: @GustavoMagalhães Looks like your comment came seconds before my answer to my own question! :P Maybe pygame would have been simpler than my solution but now I have a solution using PySide. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: If your problem was resolved, can you please share the answer with us. I am also struggling with the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @abhilash_goyal Did you check out my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I clearly wasn't able to solve this with Tkinter.

However, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902183/qimage-to-numpy-array-using-pyside). It turns out that this is possible with Qt by using the Python bindings provided by [PySide](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide) (PyQt would probably also have worked). The class [`QImage`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html) contains a method called [`constBits`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QImage.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QImage.constBits) which returns a memory view of the pixel data. This can then be turned into a Numpy array using [`numpy.asarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html).

While a QImage instance isn't a widget object and hence is never itself rendered by Qt, it can be [drawn](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPainter.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QPainter.drawImage) to an ordinary `QWidget` object. If then `QWidget` is subclassed, the methods `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` can be overridden in the subclass and made to draw for example a [QPainterPath](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QPainterPath.html) in the `QImage` object, as done [here](https://github.com/kkonopko/Paint).